# read tweets via Twitter API?

Tags: c#, twitter, twitter-oauth

If Alice, Bob and cat granted your app Access

Can the app get a global feed from  all users that granted your app?

how will your app get notified of a new tweet? Are we able to get user tweet content from every user at once?

Comment: "Are we able to get user tweet content from every user at once?" --- what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

> Can the app get a global feed from all users that granted your app?

No, you still need a token. Retrieving a token requires the user interaction

> how will your app get notified of a new tweet?

It won't. You can request periodically the tweets list though

Comment: Say we have one million users,  our app must get list of tweets one user at a time? What I want to do is monitor user has entered command text in tweet, if command entered our app performs function... however this means we have to monitor all tweets sent out ?

Comment: @001: yep, it's all like you said

Comment: oh no, that's going to be hard to scale, ok if we have the user mention our twitterbotusername, we only have to monitor our twitterbotusername right?